# weighted sampling from posterior distribution (i.e. regression predictions)

Tags: bootstrap, posterior, method-comparison

I am comparing measurement instruments A and B to assess their agreement on measuring feature x.

Measurements with A are cheap. I have made measurements on thousands of randomly selected objects with A, so I know the distribution of feature x in this large sample, and it's likely a good approximation to the distribution of x in the real world. It is heavily right-skewed, with lower boundary at zero, mode around zero, and decreasing probability for higher values.

Measuring with B is expensive. Thus, from all objects measured with A, I have selected a small sample of objects which I then also measured with B. I sampled so that the full **range** of values of x in the large sample is represented. Thus, in the small sample, the distribution of x is more or less uniform. Compared to the large sample, higher values of x are overrepresented.

For the small sample I found a significant proportional bias between the methods: A counts more x than B, and this difference increases with the amount of x in the object.

I now want to know how the differences between A and B would accumulate in a realistic sample, i.e. one where the distribution of x is the one I see in the large sample of measurements with A (i.e. right-skewed, etc. instead of uniform). Since high values of x are uncommon, the proportional bias might turn out to be less of a problem in such a sample.

*My question: Is there a way to sample from the regression results (or the small sample of differences?) to calculate the distribution of differences A-B given a certain probability distribution of x?*

This is what it looks like (simulated data):

[image]

A histogram of the distribution of A-B would now show them centered around 10, with a more or less normal distribution. How can I find out what the distribution of these differences would look like if we had drawn randomly instead of uniformly from the larger sample.

I really don't know where to start. I know I can use bootstrapping to sample from regression results, but how do I bootstrap with a certain probability distribution? How do I even estimate the "true" probability distribution from my large sample?

Code that created the plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggExtra)

# We have a large sample of measurements made with method A
# they follow a non-normal distribution. High values are less likely.
df <- data.frame(a = rgamma(2000, 1, .05))

# For a small subsample we also made measures with method B
# Oobjects in this subsample were selected uniformly
# from the range of values in A...
# ...However, there is a difference between the measures 
# from A and B, expressed as a linear function here:
add_bias <- function(a) 0.8 * a + rnorm(n=1, sd=5) 

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(bin = cut(a, 50)) %>%
  group_by(bin) %>%
  mutate(b = ifelse(row_number() == 1, add_bias(a), NA),
         d = a-b,
         m = a+b/2)

# plot A vs. B
p <- ggplot(df, aes(a, b)) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color = "white") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) +
  coord_equal()

ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram", margins = "x") # plotting distr. of A along x axis
```

Comment: Could you provide some data-example that is similar to your data? It would make it easier to understand your problem.

Comment: Hi, I added an example. I hope it's easier to understand now.

Comment: Could you treat it like a multiple imputation problem? The B values are missing and you impute them from A knowing the regression relationship. Perhaps the R package mice might help. There are other ways to do imputation of course.